# Sentence tokenization of sentences that do not have periods

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

What is the current state of art solution for tokenizing text which lack period into sentences ? Is this even possible? if so, what program/implementation do you recommend for this task (R, python, Java,  etc)?

For example,

```
hi I am a boy I am a student I like food
```

into

```
hi.
I am a boy.
I am a student.
I like food.
```

Comment: I think the content-matter issues are too substantial to be addressed on this site, which is about data analysis. You might try http://cs.stackexchange.com . (This is really a computational linguistics problem, but I don't think there's a Stack Exchange site for that.)

Comment: There is a linguistics stackexchange though. http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Check out this excellent solution https://github.com/notAI-tech/deepsegment, worked for my usecase perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking specifically for a ML approach to the problem, you may want to check the RNN - in particular Character-Level Language Models. This [article](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) has explanation of them, and the author provides [code](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn) on Github. The examples in the article manage to deal with code syntax, so the model should be fine for predicting punctuation, as long as you have a suitable training dataset.

However, ML perspective may not be the best approach, as it will probably retain some non zero error rate, regardless of the amount of training. I imagine that a [tree parsing](http://beta.visl.sdu.dk/visl/en/parsing/automatic/trees.php) of a sentence can provide indication of transitioning from simple sentence to a complex one. [This](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/link/construct-page-4.cgi) parser detects superfluous word(s) which could be used as a test whether the provided text should be still broken down into separate sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Take any reasonable word-level RNN model (or character if truly necessary), download the Wikipedia corpus or really any large text corpus. Then form a training set of sentences where the RNN predicts whether there should be a period or not. In other words take a batch of sentences and remove he periods, and then have the RNN predict their locations.